# Can't get text values of JSON object with jQuery/knockout

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js

Alright I'm a little fuzzy on iterating through javascript objects still, so hopefully you guys can clear this up for me. I'm using jQuery and Knockout to spit out server data sent as JSON. Everything seems to be working great except the actual values of the array don't seem to be applying, but I DO get the table rows constructing and there are no errors, so it has to be with my Guest(data){} function. I feel like I'm probably pointing it to the key instead of the  value. Take a look at my code and JSON structure and tell me what you think.

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: guests'>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind='value: name'></td>
            <td data-bind='value: email'></td>
            <td data-bind='value: guests'></td>
            <td data-bind='value: code'></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<body>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function Guest(data){
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.email = ko.observable(data.email);
    this.guests = ko.observable(data.guests);
    this.code = ko.observable(data.code);   
}

function guestListViewModel(){
    //Data
    var self = this;
    self.guests = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON('/php/guests_json.php', function(json) {
        var mappedGuests = $.map(json, function(item) { return new Guest(item) });
        console.log(mappedGuests);
        self.guests(mappedGuests);
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new guestListViewModel);

</script>
```

Heres what the JSON looks like from the server.

```
[{
    "id":"8",
    "name":"Greg",
    "email":"greg1@google.com",
    "guests":"1",
    "code":"GVTRKwRPXD2rETD10BMCWWAB",
    "checked_in":"0"},
{
    "id": ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahh I figured it out. It had nothing to do with my JSON object which was working perfectly. You have to be careful what kind of data-bind you apply to elements. I was using an inputs 'value' binder instead of a text spans 'text' binder.

This fixed it:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: guests'>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind='text: name'></td>
            <td data-bind='text: email'></td>
            <td data-bind='text: guests'></td>
            <td data-bind='text: code'></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json returns an array of objects. Perhaps try passing in the first value of the array (the one with the objects) like this:

```
var mappedGuests = $.map(json[0], function(item) { return new Guest(item) });
```

Comment: Afraid that did not work, and it looks like I get far less rows happening then the returned data. The console log has the subobjects there, they are just empty.

Comment: Well having a look at the outputs of an example next to my outputs, everything seems to be working sort of the same way it has to be with what I'm doing with Knockout.